# java htmlunit running external javascript in existing dom

Tags: java, javascript, dom, htmlunit

How to I run a javascript on my HD in an existing dom?

```
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
            LogFactory.getFactory().setAttribute("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");
            URL url = new URL ("http//google.com");

            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
```

I want to run "88349.js" here within "page" and get the return data for that url.

Comment: no one really some one must know how to.